# SQL divide issue in having clause

Tags: sql, oracle

When I am trying to do this

```
select first_name from employees 
group by salary,first_name
having salary between 0 and 4800
```

I am getting 49 records

When I am trying to do this I am getting no results

```
select first_name from employees 
group by salary,first_name
having salary between 0 and (max(salary)/5)
```

Here `select max(salary)/5 from employees fetches` : 4800

This is simple but I don't know what silly mistake I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement

```
select first_name from employees 
group by salary,first_name
having salary between 0 and (max(salary)/5)
```

you're grouping by salary and first_name, which is likely grouping by just one row.  You're essentially looking for X that's between 0 and X/5, which is likely to return no results.

In this statement

```
select max(salary)/5 from employees fetches
```

you're grouping by nothing, so you get the max salary of everyone.

I think this

```
select first_name from employees 
WHERE salary between 0 and (SELECT max(salary) FROM employees)/5
```

is what you're looking for

Comment: I got your point but how should I do it without using nested query

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aggregate functions in where clause.

Use this:

```
select first_name from employees 
group by salary,first_name
having salary between 0 and (SELECT max(salary)/5 from employees)
```

Comment: no no @Cdeez, you are wrong, we can use aggregate functions in having clause.

Comment: @ankit5607san: oh sorry for the mistake. My answer applies for a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subquery to avoid the second pass over the data:

```
select first_name
from (select first_name
            ,salary
            ,max(salary) over () max_salary
      from employees)
where salary between 0 and max_salary/5
group by salary,first_name;
```

Although I don't know why you're grouping by salary and first name.

Comment: Put the subquery in a with clause to increase readability if you don't like using subqueries.